# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ripple.js

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

Hello my problem is to develop phonegap application in HTML5 with the Visual Studio tools for apache cordova 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx
the error write when I debug application is

> Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.) ripple.js
>   (37,13099)
>
> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated
>   because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For
>   more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.> ripple.js (50,28958)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) ripple.js

thank you for the help

Comment: any source code?  not enough information!

Comment: Seems the issue is more related to the emulator. See if you will get the same error when debugging a fresh new cordova project. Did you run into issue if you select an emulator other than Ripple?

Answer (score 4):

May be part of the answer:
For the second error (not found 404), what worked for me is to copy `config.xml` to the root path (where your source code is).

For the first error (synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`, which is not important for the emulating process, but you may want to see a "clear" console log) just edit ripple.js

```
[MAIN_DRIVE]:\Users\[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\pkg\hosted
```

In the line that the emulator complains about, look for the xhr request.
Change

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", utils.appLocation() + fileName, false);
```

to

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", utils.appLocation() + fileName, true);
```

and you are done, Hope this helps.
These errors are not related by the way.

Comment: Your first tip worked for me (vote up :)), but I don't know where to edit the ripple.js file. I found it at the location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac ,but inside the file there is no "xmlHttp.open(..."

Comment: Found the file at [MAIN_DRIVE]:\Users\[YOUR_USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\ripple-emulator\pkg\hosted -> edit answer

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me in the two cases. Seems to be OK.

By the way:
'the root path (where your source code is)' : the www folder of the project in VS2015

And the ripple.js file found in:
always for VS2015 as  Bjoerg.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error because my npm version was at 3.3.6 which apparantly has some kind of bug in it. Updating node and npm fixed it for me:

```
npm install npm@3.3.7 -g
```

I've updated node by simply downloading and installing the latest version from nodejs.org.