# Cordova ripple.js failed to load resource error

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Created a default project without modifications, no build errors, but it failed to run and showed errors when running Ripple-Nexus(Galaxy).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262807/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-r) copying your config.xml into your www directory should resolve the ripple.js not found error.
Anyway it seems that the Ripple Simulator works well, even if you get the error, so in the end I found myself ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! The simulator shows Wait and Fire buttons, it seems to work after clicking the Wait button, but it shows the same error again when clicking the Fire button. Ok, I will ignore the error.