# Ripple emulator local storage not working - mac

Tags: cordova, storage, local, ripple

Local storage issue
Hello.
I am doing a phonegap todolist tutorial on youtube and using Ripple to test.

When I try saving to local storage i get errors. is there something i need to turn on, set up or install ?

these are the errors in my console:

```
ripple.js:37 Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Gray. Hot.)
ripple.js:50 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is      deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's  experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ripple.js:50 GET http://localhost:8000/config.xml 404 (File not found)   (anonymous function) @ ripple.js:50module.exports.initialize @    ripple.js:50_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13_baton.pass @    ripple.js:13_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13(anonymous function) @ ripple.js:38
ripple.js:50 POST http://localhost:8000/ripple/user-agent 501    (Unsupported method ('POST'))(anonymous function) @    ripple.js:50setUserAgent @ ripple.js:39_baton.pass @    ripple.js:13_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13_baton.pass @     ripple.js:13_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13_baton.pass @     ripple.js:13_baton.pass @ ripple.js:13(anonymous function) @ ripple.js:38
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Setting the user agent server side failed.
ripple.js:37 cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)
localhost/:8 The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.
ripple.js:37 cordova :: fired deviceready event!
```

This is the index.js

```
//save to local storage
var taskList = new Array();

$( document ).ready(function(){

//add to list from input
var $newTaskInput = $('#newTaskInput');
var $taskList = $('#taskList');

//Touch events for swipe left and right
var taskTouchStart;
var taskTouchEnd;
var taskTouchStartX;
var taskTouchEndX;

//save to local storage
//check if device allows local storage
if(window.localStorage)
{
    taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('taskList')); 
}

if(null !== taskList)
{   

    //loop through stored data.
    for(i=0;i<taskList.length;i++)
    {
        //add saved data
        var newTask = '<li data-key="' + taskList[i].key + '"><span>' + taskList[i].task + '</span></li>';
        $taskList.append(newTask);
    }
} else {
    //list empty
    taskList = new Array();
}


//add to list in ui
$('#addNewTask').on('click', function() {

    //use date instead of index to identify each task
    var key = Date.now();

    //add to list from input and add the date to each li as a key.
    var newTask = '<li data-key="' + key + '"><span>' + $newTaskInput.val() + '</span></li>';
    $taskList.append( newTask );

    //add stored data array
    $taskList.push({key:key, task:$newTaskInput.val(), done:false}); //the key for key is key on line29

    //save it
    if(window.localStorage)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList) ); //convert array in to a string
    }

    //if clicked without input. val is empty
    $newTaskInput.val('');

});


//TOUCH START
$taskList.on('touchstart', 'li', function(e){ //e means each

    //make the position 0 for x and y where you touch.
    var start = document.elementFromPoint( e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY); 

    //get the id(Key) of the li touched
    taskTouchStart = $(start).attr('data-key');

    //get the start position
    taskTouchStartX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

});

//TOUCH END
$taskList.on('touchend', 'li', function(e){ //e means each

    var $end;
    var $this = $(this);

    var end = document.elementFromPoint( e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY); 
    $end = $(end); 

    //get the id(Key) of the li touched
    taskTouchEnd = $end.attr('data-key');

    //get the end position
    taskTouchEndX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

    //get id again to make sure its the same.
    if( taskTouchStart == taskTouchEnd )
    {
        // swipe right to add class
        // swipe right a second time to remove it
        if( taskTouchStartX < taskTouchEndX )
        {
            if($this.hasClass('done'))
            {
                $this.removeClass('done');
                //alert("remove");
            } else {
                $this.addClass('done');
                //alert("add");
            }
        }else{
            //remove from storage
            taskList = $.grep(taskList, function(e){ return e.key != taskTouchEnd;}); //return if key is different
            //save again
            if(window.localStorage)
            {
                window.localStorage.setItem('taskList', JSON.stringify(taskList) ); //convert array in to a string
            }

            //remove $end
            $end.remove(); //remove current element
        }

    }

    // to make sure it works 
    // inspect element - click resources
    // on the left click the drop down for local storage and select http://localhost:8000


});
 });
```

This is the html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1)
        document.getElementById('metaViewport').setAttribute('content', 'width='+screen.width+', initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">

        <h1>To Do List </h1>

        <div id="newTaskSection">
            <input type="text" id="newTaskInput" placeholder="New Task"></input>
            <button id="addNewTask">Add</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="taskList">
        </ul>

    </div>

<!--         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks
ricky

Comment: If you're worried about the file not found take a look in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512692/cordova-ripple-js-failed-to-load-resource-error/34535587#34535587). It's not really a problem. If your looking for an answer to your localstorage problem, please provide some more information, for example a snippet of your code. And no you should not need to install or set up anything ;)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. i fixed the file not found and i have added the rest of the code above. this is the tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCOneRpqVAs   i can not see anything different